# Python Pandas DatetimeIndex conversion

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dictionary containing two numpy arrays, one in datetime.dateime the other a masked array of data. I am trying to get this into Pandas with the the datetime array used as a DatetimeIndex but I am failing.

```
In [62]: dict1
Out[62]: 
{'filltimes': array([datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 12, 0, 1),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 12, 30, 1),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 12, 13, 0, 1), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 14, 19, 0, 1),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 14, 19, 30, 1),
       datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 14, 20, 0, 1)], dtype=object),
 'fillvals': masked_array(data = [5.553 2.604 2.604 ..., 16.896 17.271 18.022],
             mask = [False False False ..., False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
}

In [63]: type(dict1)
Out[63]: dict

In [64]: type(dict1['filltimes'])
Out[64]: numpy.ndarray

In [65]: type(dict1['filltimes'][0])
Out[65]: datetime.datetime

In [66]: pd1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

In [67]: type(pd1)
Out[67]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [68]: type(pd1['filltimes'])
Out[68]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [69]: type(pd1['filltimes'][0])
Out[69]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [70]: pd1.resample('D', how = 'mean')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-8ddb5f2158aa> in <module>()
----> 1 pd1.resample('D', how = 'mean')

/Users/andrew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
   2777                               fill_method=fill_method, convention=convention,
   2778                               limit=limit, base=base)
-> 2779         return sampler.resample(self).__finalize__(self)
   2780 
   2781     def first(self, offset):

/Users/andrew/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.pyc in resample(self, obj)
     99             return obj
    100         else:  # pragma: no cover
--> 101             raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex')
    102 
    103         rs_axis = rs._get_axis(self.axis)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex

In [71]: pd1.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(pd1['filltimes'])))
Out[71]: 
                    filltimes  fillvals
2013-08-12 12:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 12:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 13:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 13:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 14:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 14:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 15:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 15:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 16:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 16:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 17:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 17:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 18:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 18:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 19:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 19:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 20:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 20:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 21:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 21:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 22:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 22:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 23:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-12 23:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 00:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 00:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 01:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 01:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 02:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 02:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 03:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 03:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 04:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 04:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 05:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 05:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 06:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 06:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 07:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 07:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 08:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 08:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 09:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 09:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 10:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 10:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 11:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 11:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 12:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 12:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 13:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 13:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 14:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 14:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 15:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 15:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 16:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 16:30:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 17:00:01       NaT       NaN
2013-08-13 17:30:01       NaT       NaN
                          ...       ...

[1601 rows x 2 columns]

In [72]:
```

As you can see, the reindexing doesn't produce what I would expect or at least hoped it would. Not only is all the data lost but the reindexing isn't kept:

```
In [72]: pd1
Out[72]: 
             filltimes  fillvals
0  2013-08-12 12:00:01     5.553
1  2013-08-12 12:30:01     2.604
2  2013-08-12 13:00:01     2.604
3  2013-08-12 13:30:01     2.604
4  2013-08-12 14:00:01     2.101
5  2013-08-12 14:30:01     2.666
6  2013-08-12 15:00:01     3.420
7  2013-08-12 15:30:01     2.666
8  2013-08-12 16:00:01     2.478
9  2013-08-12 16:30:01     2.227
10 2013-08-12 17:00:01     2.729
11 2013-08-12 17:30:01     1.662
12 2013-08-12 18:00:01     2.792
13 2013-08-12 18:30:01     1.599
14 2013-08-12 19:00:01     1.411
15 2013-08-12 19:30:01     1.976
16 2013-08-12 20:00:01     1.536
17 2013-08-12 20:30:01     1.411
18 2013-08-12 21:00:01     1.160
19 2013-08-12 21:30:01     0.720
20 2013-08-12 22:00:01     0.720
21 2013-08-12 22:30:01     1.034
22 2013-08-12 23:00:01     0.783
23 2013-08-12 23:30:01     0.783
24 2013-08-13 00:00:01     0.846
25 2013-08-13 00:30:01     0.720
26 2013-08-13 01:00:01     0.783
27 2013-08-13 01:30:01     0.783
28 2013-08-13 02:00:01     0.595
29 2013-08-13 02:30:01     0.720
30 2013-08-13 03:00:01     1.034
31 2013-08-13 03:30:01     0.720
32 2013-08-13 04:00:01     1.160
33 2013-08-13 04:30:01     1.034
34 2013-08-13 05:00:01     1.599
35 2013-08-13 05:30:01     1.662
36 2013-08-13 06:00:01     1.599
37 2013-08-13 06:30:01     2.227
38 2013-08-13 07:00:01     1.474
39 2013-08-13 07:30:01     4.173
40 2013-08-13 08:00:01     2.855
41 2013-08-13 08:30:01     3.231
42 2013-08-13 09:00:01     3.420
43 2013-08-13 09:30:01     3.420
44 2013-08-13 10:00:01     3.043
45 2013-08-13 10:30:01     3.733
46 2013-08-13 11:00:01     4.675
47 2013-08-13 11:30:01     5.114
48 2013-08-13 12:00:01     5.490
49 2013-08-13 12:30:01     4.612
50 2013-08-13 13:00:01     4.235
51 2013-08-13 13:30:01     3.796
52 2013-08-13 14:00:01     3.545
53 2013-08-13 14:30:01     4.110
54 2013-08-13 15:00:01     3.671
55 2013-08-13 15:30:01     3.169
56 2013-08-13 16:00:01     3.231
57 2013-08-13 16:30:01     3.420
58 2013-08-13 17:00:01     2.792
59 2013-08-13 17:30:01     2.792
                   ...       ...

[1601 rows x 2 columns]

In [73]:
```

I would really appreciate a pointer or two on where I am going wrong here. This whole date/time thing with Pandas is driving up the wall.

Comment: present a small copy-pastable example (your example is a shortened version).

Comment: Have you experimented with set_index? pd1 = pd1.set_index('filltimes')